# Facebook SDK does not work after bitbucket pull in other computer with Xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, git, bitbucket

I have a project where I am using `FacebookSDK` framework. I have followed the guide and everything works well in my computer, the problem is when I make a push into **bitbucket** repository and one mate make pull in his computer to work with the project there.

He gets this error `FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h` file not found.. We have looked in Framework search paths and the path had different user name ( my computer's name).

Which is the good way to install it? We have downloaded both FacebookSDK.pkg and installed it. its default path is /User/USERNAME/Documents/FacebookSDK/....  I have tried like they do in the video and I have added the Framework and bundle file into Framework folder of xcode without copy it.

I also have tried to put the framework in the Project folder and then add then add to the xcode project. it does not work either.

So, how people do this when they work in a work group with BitBucket or github(I guess is the same)

I also have this warning, APPLE MATCH-O LINKER WARNING ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/xxxxxxxxx/Documents/OS/project_name'

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/xxxxxxxx/Documents/FacebookSDK'

In Project/Build settings Framework Search path when we make commit we have both paths..

Answer (score 0):

I added the facebook sdk by following method

Click on the Project->Target->Link Binary with Library-> + -> add other and go where your frame work is, it should be in documents. 
here you go. !!!!

Comment: it's still happening the same.. it is weird I guess.. Do you work in a workgroup with the facebook sdk?